# IntelliJ - navigating between Spring config and classes with keyboard, and using icons on outline with keyboard

Tags: intellij-idea

I would like to know if there is a keyboard shortcut that would move between Spring config and its classes (icon on editor outline with mouse click).

And one more thing is there any way to display data of icons on the outline? That means: I am on the line which has an icon or two on the outline. Now i would like shortcut that would "click" there, so it would for example show all classes implementing interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `Go To` | `Related File` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>) for Spring.
- `Go To` | `Super Method` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) for Interface/Overridden classes.

There is no generic action that will trigger a click on an icon.